# How can I point to this unique image on a webpage with Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I have a website which contains lots of images. I am trying to get the "src" of a specific image on the webpage. However I can't seem to find a way to precisely only point to that specific image. Since every possible way that I know of always returns more results.

If you go to :
https://weheartit.com/entry/349292873

You will see the one biggest image staring directly right at you.

When the poster doesn't provide title (which I found out later) it gets an alt attribute of "Image by {user}" and so I tried to use the `[contains(text(), 'Image by')]` identifier. This obviously doesn't work if the user actually provides the title. On the example webpage that I listed above the image has an alt of 'aesthetic, couple, and cute image' for example.

And so I tried to point to the tree where the element is listed by doing:

```
//div/div/a/img
```

Which returns 5 different results of the same tree. And so I tried using nth:child instead by doing:

```
"(//div/div/a/img)[4]"
```

which works on most pages however on some it points to the websites logo instead of the image that I am trying to download because the nth structure is broken and it's 4th child suddenly becomes something else than what I am trying to download.

Which leads me to my initial question. How can I correctly point ONLY to the actual image that I am trying to download. I couldn't find a way to do so and I would be grateful if anyone could help me out with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly described the issue.
So,

1 Wait for this element to become visible

2 Get its attribute with `get_attribute("src")`

I used css locator, but it can also be done with xpath.

**Solution**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://weheartit.com/entry/349292873')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".panel-large.list.js-entry-panel>a>img")))
link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".panel-large.list.js-entry-panel>a>img").get_attribute("src")
print(link)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
https://data.whicdn.com/images/349292873/original.gif
```